# Generic gamepad controllers not working with It Takes Two

Tags: controllers, it-takes-two

I have the 0810-0001-Twin USB Gamepad  on Windows.
It works fine in gamepad testers on websites.
However when I play It Takes Two, it does not pick up the controllers.
Is the game limited to only specific controllers? Can I proxy my generic controllers to make it look like the ones it want?

Answer (score 1):

It seems to require xbox controllers, so using this emulator solved it for me.

https://github.com/x360ce/x360ce/wiki/Beta-Testing

Answer (score 0):

Are you using steam to play the game? If so does it work in big picture mode? It may be that case that steam is trying to set a config for your game on launch but it's not working.

To disable this feature disable/uncheck the option 'Generic Gamepad Configuration Support' from the following menu: Steam (top left UI) > Setting > Controller, This might open steam in big picture mode with the options.

This solution applies regardless of whether you launch it in big picture mode.